# unwanted text message when unable to answer a call

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

When I am unable to answer the phone, sometimes it will tell the person I am busy or at the movies.  How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Open your Phone/Dialer app and go into its Settings.  Look for "Quick Reply" or similar and you should be able to disable it or remove the entries.